# Split a GeoTIFF (BigTIFF) file into subsets with a specific overlap in Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, bigtiff

I have a BigTIFF file that I need to split into tiles with a set tile size and overlap. I have a script for this using `PIL`:

```
tile_height = tile_width = 1000
overlap = 80
stride = tile_height - overlap
start_num=0

def crop(infile, tile_height, tile_width, stride, img_dict, prj_name):
    im = Image.open(infile) 
    img_width, img_height = im.size
    print(im.size)
    print(img_width * img_height / (tile_height - stride) / (tile_width - stride))
    count = 0
    for r in range(0, img_height-tile_height+1, stride):
        for c in range(0, img_width-tile_width+1, stride):
            #tile = im[r:r+100, c:c+100]
            box = (c, r, c+tile_width, r+tile_height)
            top_pixel = [c,r]
            img_dict[prj_name + "---" + str(count) + ".png"] = top_pixel
            count += 1
            yield im.crop(box)
img = Image
img_dict = {}

# create the dir if it doesn't already exist
if not os.path.exists(img_dir):
    os.makedirs(img_dir)

# break it up into crops
for k, piece in enumerate(crop(infile, tile_height, tile_width, stride, img_dict, prj_name), start_num):
    img=Image.new('RGB', (tile_height, tile_width), (255, 255, 255))
    print(img.size)
    print(piece.size)
    img.paste(piece)
    image_name = prj_name + "---%s.png" % k
    path=os.path.join(img_dir, image_name)
    img.save(path)

#add a json file with all image names and geospatial metadata 
full_dict = {"image_name" : infile,
            "image_locations" : img_dict,
             "crs" : str(dataset.crs)
            }

with open(img_dir + '/data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(full_dict, fp)
```

I can't use PIL on my other rasters, as they are "BigTiff" files and not supported in PIL. I am looking for a way to translate this script into another module keeping these exact parameters. I need the parameters and naming methods to stay exactly the same as I'm using these tiles for a deep learning model that I have already created.

I have never used something like GDAL before, but I've read that this may be my best bet for Big TIFF tiling? I would really like to find a way to do this in Python.

Comment: [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#reading-raster-data) should pretty much drop into your existing script since it'll return a numpy array.  It wraps gdal but is much more convenient to work with than the Python bindings.  It normally comes with BigTIFF support but depends on how it was built, I believe.  If you grab it via conda/conda-forge it should, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `for` loop and read one tile at a time using  `gdal.ReadAsArray()`, passing both an offset and a window size as arguments. This function returns a `numpy` array which you can then easily export to a JPG file.

Your code could look something:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

# open TIFF file (reading) mode and get dimensions
ds = gdal.Open(r'C:\path\to\your\raster.tif', 0)
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize

# define tile size and number of pixels to move in each direction
tile_size_x = 256
tile_size_y = 256
stride_x = 128
stride_y = 128

for x_off in range(0, width, stride_y):
    for y_off in range(0, height, stride_x):

    # read tile
    arr = ds.ReadAsArray(x_off, y_off, tile_size_x, tile_size_y)

    # export image using either PIL, gdal or some other library
```

Of course, you'll need to deal with the edge cases when there are not enough pixels left in the x or y axis.

Answer (score 0):

CLI can also be used as below. Make suitable changes to use function parameters for tile and overlap sizes.

```
def generate_tiles(input_geotiff):
  targetDir=ntpath.basename(input_geotiff).split('.')[0]+"_tiles"
  Path(targetDir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  command = "gdal_retile.py  -ps 512 512 -overlap 128 -targetDir  "+ targetDir  + " "  + input_geotiff
  print(os.popen(command).read())
  return targetDir
```